# How to download the same Url image from Http and both not repeat the httpRequest and async execution?

Tags: android

I have a ListView in my Application,and the item of ListView will show the Image.
So I need to async loader to load image from Http.

Now I Use the Bitmapfun for Google，But Youknow,it's complex，at least I think so.

So I want to reCode it，and come across a problem.

> How to download the same Url image from Http and both not repeat the
>   httpRequest and async execution?

Because in the items of ListView,maybe showing the same image.
In Bitmapfun,google "synchronized"  the process，So it could not concurrency for download image。

help me!  Thk.T_T

.........Sorry,English is not good.

A ListView,For example,have 5 items.
Every item have an ImageView to show Image.
I use AsyncTask to making Http requests,download it,and put into cache,and display it.

mayBe the five image was

"Hxxp://xxx.com/1.jpg",

"Hxxp://xxx.com/2.jpg",

"Hxxp://xxx.com/3.jpg",

"Hxxp://xxx.com/1.jpg",

"Hxxp://xxx.com/1.jpg"

So the three of the Http request are the same.
But the AsyncTask is at the same time to work.
So the other two Http request was repeat.

The problem I want to solve is "How to download the image for AsyncTask But If the Same Url only download once?".....

Edit：
Use Lazy List:

```
 private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null){
        Log.d("ImageLoader", " From Cache" + url);
        return b;
    }
    //from web
    try {
        Log.d("ImageLoader", " Begin Downloading" + url);
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
           memoryCache.clear();
       return null;
    }
}
```

Init ListView and the log is:

> 04-09 10:44:31.900: D/ImageLoader(8578):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg
>   04-09 10:44:31.910: D/ImageLoader(8578):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg
>   04-09 10:44:31.910: D/ImageLoader(8578):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg
>   04-09 10:44:31.910: D/ImageLoader(8578):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg
>   04-09 10:44:31.930: D/ImageLoader(8578):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg
>   04-09 10:44:33.090: I/MemoryCache(8578): cache size=44032 length=1
>   04-09 10:44:33.090: D/ImageLoader(8578):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-UBmLbPELvoQ/URqucCdv0kI/AAAAAAAAAbs/IdNhr2VQoQs/s1024/Apre%2525CC%252580s%252520la%252520Pluie.jpg
>   04-09 10:44:33.140: I/MemoryCache(8578): cache size=44032 length=1
>   04-09 10:44:33.140: D/ImageLoader(8578):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-UBmLbPELvoQ/URqucCdv0kI/AAAAAAAAAbs/IdNhr2VQoQs/s1024/Apre%2525CC%252580s%252520la%252520Pluie.jpg

Use https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

```
if (bmp != null && !bmp.isRecycled()) {
        Log.d("ImageLoader", " From Cache " + uri);
        if (configuration.loggingEnabled)
            L.i(LOG_LOAD_IMAGE_FROM_MEMORY_CACHE, memoryCacheKey);

        if (options.shouldPostProcess()) {
            ImageLoadingInfo imageLoadingInfo = new ImageLoadingInfo(uri, imageView, targetSize, options, listener,
                    engine.getLockForUri(uri));
            ProcessAndDisplayImageTask displayTask = new ProcessAndDisplayImageTask(engine, bmp, imageLoadingInfo, options.getHandler());
            engine.submit(displayTask);
        } else {
            options.getDisplayer().display(bmp, imageView);
            listener.onLoadingComplete(uri, imageView, bmp);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("ImageLoader", " Begin Downloading " + uri);
        if (options.shouldShowStubImage()) {
            imageView.setImageResource(options.getStubImage());
        } else {
            if (options.isResetViewBeforeLoading()) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
            }
        }

        ImageLoadingInfo imageLoadingInfo = new ImageLoadingInfo(uri, imageView, targetSize, options, listener,
                engine.getLockForUri(uri));
        LoadAndDisplayImageTask displayTask = new LoadAndDisplayImageTask(engine, imageLoadingInfo, options.getHandler());
        engine.submit(displayTask);
    }
```

Init ListView and the log is:

> 04-09 10:23:24.590: D/ImageLoader(7336):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg
>   04-09 10:23:24.600: D/ImageLoader(7336):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg
>   04-09 10:23:24.600: D/ImageLoader(7336):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg
>   04-09 10:23:24.610: D/ImageLoader(7336):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg
>   04-09 10:23:24.610: D/ImageLoader(7336):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg
>   04-09 10:23:24.610: D/ImageLoader(7336):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-UBmLbPELvoQ/URqucCdv0kI/AAAAAAAAAbs/IdNhr2VQoQs/s1024/Apre%2525CC%252580s%252520la%252520Pluie.jpg
>   04-09 10:23:24.610: D/ImageLoader(7336):  Begin Downloading hxxps://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-UBmLbPELvoQ/URqucCdv0kI/AAAAAAAAAbs/IdNhr2VQoQs/s1024/Apre%2525CC%252580s%252520la%252520Pluie.jpg

So the httpRequest is Repeat....

Comment: I suggest you to use this one if I am not misunderstanding the requirement https://code.google.com/p/libs-for-android/wiki/ImageLoader

Comment: can you post what you have done. The question is very unclear.

Comment: You cannot download an image without making an HTTP request, and you certainly don't want to do it on UI thread, so what solution are you looking for?

Comment: @Raghunandan I am Sorry,I alreay post the new description! Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/thest1/LazyList is the superb.

Comment: @zh_gino you can use lazy list or universal Image loader. Both use caching and url as the key. If image exists in cahce display from cache else download cache and display.

Comment: @Raghunandan,Thanks,I know ,the image maybe use the lazy loading,My Question is when the first time.the five imageview to lazy loading at the same time to show,and all can't find the bitmap in the cache,and then they will to download at the same time,but the 3 of urls is same,the Three image are the same,the two aside httpRequest will be repeat,how to avoid it.

Comment: @zh_gino once images are downloaded it is cached. Your url is the key. If it is present in cache no need to download again. display the same image. Also why do you have to display the same image? Is this not redundant.?

Comment: @Raghunandan，yep，the one process ,to find the cache,use the url as key,if the value of cache is exist,to display it,or no exist,to download.But,the Five image loading are Concurrent，it means will have five processes to Run on the same time,They all to find the cache,and All Cann't find the value in the cache,so they all will to download. The same Url 's process will be repeat..

Comment: @zh_gino Images are displayed according to the view visible. suppose you can display two images at a time in listview. Only two images are downloaded. Next when you scroll another set of 2 images is downloaded and displayed. So all images are not downloaded at the same time.

Comment: @Raghunandan,thks,if the 2 images are the same url,the download will be repeat,because I think the same images only be down once enough。But in fact，is two download.

Comment: @zh_gino you are not getting my point. try the lazy list yourself you will know how it works. then you can come back post a new question. I have tried both lazy list and universal image loader by repeating the urls for downloading. It works fine. I will just add a snapshot to my answer. check it.

Comment: @Raghunandan,thanks,yes,I use similar code now，and I think it works fine,I want to solve the repeat download ‘s problem,is want to reduce the traffic...

Comment: @zh_gino thats why you need to use lazy list

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lazy Loading or Universal Image Loader

Lazy List is lazy loading of images from sdcard or fomr server using urls. It is like on demand loading images.

Images can be cached to local sd card or phone mmeory. Url is considered the key. If the key is present in sdcard display images from sd card else display image by downloading from server and cache the same to location of your choice. The cache limit can set. You can also choose your own location to cache images. Cache can also be cleared.

Instead of user waiting to download large images and then displaying lazy list loads images on demand. Since images area cached you can display images offline.

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList. Lazy List

In your getview

imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageurl, imageview);
ImageLoader Display method

```
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) //url and imageview as parameters
{
imageViews.put(imageView, url);
Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);   //get image from cache using url as key
if(bitmap!=null)         //if image exists
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  //dispaly iamge
 else   //downlaod image and dispaly. add to cache.
 {
    queuePhoto(url, imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
 }
```

}
An alternative to Lazy List is Universal Image Loader

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. It is based on Lazy List(works on same principle). But it has lot of other configurations. I would prefer to use *Universal Image Loader* coz it gives you more configuration options. You can display a error image if downlaod failed. Can display images with rounded corners. Can cache on disc or memory. Can compress image.

In your custom adapter constructor

```
 File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(a, "your folder");

// Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
// Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
      // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
     .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
     .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
     .enableLogging()
     .build();
 // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
 imageLoader.init(config);
  options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_id)//display stub image
.cacheInMemory()
.cacheOnDisc()
.displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
 .build();
```

In your getView()

```
 ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageview); 
 imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, image,options);//provide imageurl, imageview and options
```

You can configure with other options to suit your needs.

Along with lazy loading/Universal Image Loader you can view holder for smooth scrolling and performance. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html.

Edit:

As you can see images are displayed twice (downloaded once). However it is cached only once.
The images below are icons. I have not scaled it properly while testing. So it looks stretched.

[image]

Comment: @zh_gino i have used it and the problem does not exist. Post your lazy list code.